# Installed Russian Language Pack - security issue?

Tags: magento-1.9

A language pack has appeared in my configuration menu: "ET Russian Language Pack"

I didn't install it, and have manually deleted it.

It is coincident with increased bogus registrations, which makes me suspicious.

Any help, please?

Thanks, Brian

Comment: ET is a theme vendor, did you recently install or update a theme by them? The themes always contain some modules, maybe this one contains a language pack as well.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using composer? If so, it might be a requirement of one of the composer packages you're using. If not, we need to continue investigating.

First question would be: do you need a Russian language pack? If not, I'd say let's delete it. But first, we might want to check the language pack for suspicious code. You could check if there is JavaScript in the tags? The easiest way to check this is by searching in the folder for script tags. This won't cover all possible forms of malicious code in there, but it should cover a lot.

If you don't find anything there, you might want to continue looking for inline JavaScript. Malicious code mostly uses code that is encrypted or minified in some way. So you might also want to search for the words `eval` and `function`. If you find any of those, you should check what the code does, because normally this shouldn't be in translation files.

No matter if you found something or not, when you're not using a Russian language pack, just remove the entire `app/locale/ru_RU` folder from your site.

Since you also said that you see a lot of strange registrations, we might also want to check if your shop isn't hacked in any way. [MageReport](https://www.magereport.com) could help you out pretty well there, to find the most common hacks there are. If MageReport comes up with something, you might want to fix that asap.

You should also check if there are unknown admin or API accounts in your shop. You can check these via **System > Configuration > Permissions > Users** and **System > Web Services**. If you find any unknown users there, remove them immediately. This might mean that your site is compromised.

After you've done that, you should update all your admin users' passwords, your API users' passwords and I'd say also update the admin URL path. This should prevent a lot of vulnerabilities. But be aware that you make sure everything else is fixed first, otherwise it's easy to compromise the shop again.

After this, you might want to remove the strange customer accounts as well, just to be sure. And last but not least, if you store credit card information in your Magento installation, make sure you contact the credit card company as well.

Please let us know if the site was compromised or that you just deleted the extension.